# Some link building service got an old webpage of mine and is hosting it on another domain

Tags: copyright

Apparently they got it from archive.org.  They made no changes to the page except to throw in some links, fitting them into the context so it will look natural to a crawler.  They neglected to remove the visitor counter, that's how I found out.

They even left the copyright notice I had on the page.

They're using my images, my design, my content, my js, etc.  Even though I no longer own the domain of the original site, I seem to be last owner.

Can't find out who owns the domain so I guess I would go through the host to get in touch.

Wondering if there is any legal remedy for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any legal remedy?  Yes.  What you describe is an open-and-shut case of [copyright infringement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_infringement).

The question is how much effort and expense is involved in dealing with this.  At the simple end of things, if the webpage host is in the United States, you can send a [DMCA takedown notice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Copyright_Infringement_Liability_Limitation_Act#Take_down_and_put_back_provisions) to get the page removed; at the complex end, if the host is in a country with a lax copyright regime that isn't on good terms with your country (say, you're in the US and the host is in Russia), you may be looking at a decades-long international copyright infringement lawsuit to get the page taken down.

Comment: Also, you can report to the search engines as well.